# I am Getting Errors while Creating React App

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I am running Create React App command in Windows Powershell but it's not working and giving errors. Please help me rectify it.

I pasted this command
npx create-react-app my-app

I received these messages

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

`npm ERR!` A complete log of this run can be found in: `C:\Users\Aditi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-26T11_31_52_884Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: CRA is dead, stop using it. You can try Vite instead